# Overwrite getProductUrl function

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, base-url

The goal is that we want to be able to change the url under some conditions for all product URLs.  It seems that the solution would be to add a function to our module Observer.php.  I can't quite get it to run.  The original function is

```
public function getProductUrl($product, $additional = array())
{
    if ($this->hasProductUrl($product)) {
        if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
            $additional['_escape'] = true;
        }
        return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $additional);
    }

    return '#';
}
```

What I tried to do is just put in our Observer.php

```
/**
 * Set the url to be based from it's store not based on the location it's currently showen
 *
 * @return String url
 */
public function getProductUrl($product, $additional = array()) {

    if ($this->hasProductUrl($product)) {
        $pstore_id = array_shift(array_values($_product->getStoreIds()));
        if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() == $pstore_id){
            $purl = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $additional);//$this->getProductUrl();
        }else{
            $base = Mage::app()->getStore($pstore_id)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);
            $purl = $base.$product->getUrlPath();
        }
        if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
            $additional['_escape'] = true;
        }
        return $purl;
    }
    return '#';
}
```

But I'm not seeing any change as of yet.  What am I missing here.  Thank you.
Cheers -Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event that you can hook on for changing the method you want. 
From the piece of code you posted I conclude you want to override the `getProductUrl` method from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`. You cannot do that unless you copy the file to your local folder. [Here are more details about it.](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2011/09/why-cant-you-override-some-classes-in.html).
But you can override the product model.
For this you will need a new module (or use one that you already have).
For a new module these are the files you need (Feel free to change the namespace):
`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Catalog.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/etc/config.xml - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Easylife_Catalog_Model_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/Model/Product.php` - your version of the model

```
<?php
class Easylife_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product {
    public function getProductUrl($useSid = null){
        //your version of the method here
    }
}
```

Clear the cache and you are done.

Comment: So I did this, but what I end up with is Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in E:\inetpub\wwwroot\devstore.wsu.edu\app\code\local\Wsu\Centralprocessing\Model\Product.php on line 50 where Line 50 is the last } of the class.. Any reason this would be the case?

Comment: See the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345003/magento-class-zend-log-not-found. Maybe it helps.

Comment: fair enough, and it was do to the missing argument for the method, but.. it's still not printing the hello once I cleard the error.

Comment: ok I'm getting closer, it's seems that $this->getStoreIds() is freaking out cause $this is not the product in this method.. I guess.. not sure why that is the case though

Comment: ok cleared that with $product = $this->getProduct();  I believe (or not erroring at the least)